# ScrollView not sizing itself correctly

Tags: android, android-layout, android-scrollview

I'm trying to get a ScrollView to take up as much screen space as it needs  until it would start pushing items below (outside) it off the screen, then it needs to stop expanding and become scrolly.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" 
>

    <ScrollView 
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:background="#ff0000"
    >
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="taking\nup\lots\nof\nlines\nto\nmake\nthe\nscrollview&quot;s\ncontent\ntaller\nthan\nthe\nspace\navailable\nto\nit\nwhich\nshould\nmake\nthe\nscrollview\nstop\nabove\nthe\nbutton\nand\nbecome\nscrollable"
        /> 
        <!-- 
            android:text="just one line"
        -->
    </ScrollView>

    <Button
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="Button"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

As it is above the ScrollView fills the entire screen height and pushes the button off the bottom of the screen.
If I add `android:layout_weight="1"` to the ScrollView then it works for this case - the button is at the bottom and the ScrollView stops above it - but when the ScrollView doesn't have much content (replace the text with the one-liner) then the ScrollView doesn't shrink to fit around the content so is far too tall.

I've tried using RelativeLayout with no success - if the Button is `android:layout_below` the ScrollView then the ScrollView will push it off the bottom of the screen if it has a lot of content.

Here's what I want it to look like: in the first image the ScrollView has a lot of content and so expands to fill the available height but doesn't push the items below it (the button) offscreen, in the second image the ScrollView doesn't have much content so takes up just the height it needs allowing the items below it (the button) to move up the screen:
[image: ScrollView has a lot of content] [image: SrollView doesn't have much content]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do, is to correct the height in your code. It's a bit hacky and I would like to see another solution, but off the top of my head I do not know anything better.

What you would need is to add a `OnGlobalLayoutListener` and calculate within it the minimum of either the `ScrollView` height or the height of the container surrounding your `ScrollView` minus the height of your `Button`.

Then set the size with `setLayoutParams()` on your `ScrollView`.

And you have to remove the listener to avoid an endless loop :-)

```
    final View scrollview = findViewById(R.id.scrollview);
    final View container = findViewById(R.id.container);
    final View button = findViewById(R.id.button);
    scrollview.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            int height = scrollview.getHeight();
            int heightButton = button.getHeight();
            int heightContainer = container.getHeight();
            int min = Math.min(heightContainer - heightButton, height);
            int width = scrollview.getWidth();
            Log.v("test", "min: " + min);
            scrollview.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(width, min));

            // do not forget to remove the listener
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                scrollview.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
            }
            else {
                scrollview.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
            }
        }
    });
```

For this to work you have to use `wrap_content` as the height of the `ScrollView` in your layout file. And the outer container has to be a `RelativeLayout` so that the `Button`is rendered and has a non-zero height!

If you use paddings or margins you would have to consider those values in the computation.

Comment: Thanks Wolfram, it works! I've expanded it a bit: I'm getting the height of the ScrollView's child and overriding with that if the ScrollView's height is taller. It works in a LinearLayout if the ScrollView initially has a weight of 1, which has to be set to 0 when the height is overridden or it is ignored. The contents change dynamically so this listener can't be removed, I'm setting a flag to avoid the endless loop problem. It might be neater if I could get it into a custom widget that extends ScrollView, I'll have a look at that but it's a bit dependent on the parent's LayoutParams type.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button"
        android:background="#ff0000">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <TextView
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="taking\nup\lots\nof\nlines\nto\nmake\nthe\nscrollview&quot;s\ncontent\ntaller\nthan\nthe\nspace\navailable\nto\nit\nwhich\nshould\nmake\nthe\nscrollview\nstop\nabove\nthe\nbutton\nand\nbecome\nscrollable" />
            <TextView
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="taking\nup\lots\nof\nlines\nto\nmake\nthe\nscrollview&quot;s\ncontent\ntaller\nthan\nthe\nspace\navailable\nto\nit\nwhich\nshould\nmake\nthe\nscrollview\nstop\nabove\nthe\nbutton\nand\nbecome\nscrollable" />
            <TextView
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="taking\nup\lots\nof\nlines\nto\nmake\nthe\nscrollview&quot;s\ncontent\ntaller\nthan\nthe\nspace\navailable\nto\nit\nwhich\nshould\nmake\nthe\nscrollview\nstop\nabove\nthe\nbutton\nand\nbecome\nscrollable" />
            <TextView
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="taking\nup\lots\nof\nlines\nto\nmake\nthe\nscrollview&quot;s\ncontent\ntaller\nthan\nthe\nspace\navailable\nto\nit\nwhich\nshould\nmake\nthe\nscrollview\nstop\nabove\nthe\nbutton\nand\nbecome\nscrollable" />
            <TextView
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="taking\nup\lots\nof\nlines\nto\nmake\nthe\nscrollview&quot;s\ncontent\ntaller\nthan\nthe\nspace\navailable\nto\nit\nwhich\nshould\nmake\nthe\nscrollview\nstop\nabove\nthe\nbutton\nand\nbecome\nscrollable" />
            <TextView
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="taking\nup\lots\nof\nlines\nto\nmake\nthe\nscrollview&quot;s\ncontent\ntaller\nthan\nthe\nspace\navailable\nto\nit\nwhich\nshould\nmake\nthe\nscrollview\nstop\nabove\nthe\nbutton\nand\nbecome\nscrollable" />
            <TextView
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="taking\nup\lots\nof\nlines\nto\nmake\nthe\nscrollview&quot;s\ncontent\ntaller\nthan\nthe\nspace\navailable\nto\nit\nwhich\nshould\nmake\nthe\nscrollview\nstop\nabove\nthe\nbutton\nand\nbecome\nscrollable" />
            <TextView
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="taking\nup\lots\nof\nlines\nto\nmake\nthe\nscrollview&quot;s\ncontent\ntaller\nthan\nthe\nspace\navailable\nto\nit\nwhich\nshould\nmake\nthe\nscrollview\nstop\nabove\nthe\nbutton\nand\nbecome\nscrollable" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="Button" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks, but when the scrollview has lots of content it is still sized to the full screen height, in this case the button overlays it but you can still see the content flows behind the button. We could maybe mask that bit so we can't see it behind the button but the user will never be able to scroll to that content.

And it's similar if there isn't much content in the scrollview - the scrollview still fills the screen - I want it to resize itself to wrap the content and the button appear directly below it.

Comment: Do you want to have the button permanently on the screen and for the scrollview to scroll independent of this or to have a scrollview and when this is scrolled to the bottom to be able to see the button?

Comment: The first one - button always on the screen.

Comment: I updated the code, this allows to scroll the content in the `ScrollView` and the `Button` is always on the screen

Comment: Thanks again, but when there isn't much content in the ScrollView - remove all the TextViews except one with one line of text - the ScrollView is too tall and takes up most of the screen. I want it to size itself to wrap its content. I've added a couple of screenshots to help explain what I'm after, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just try adding fillViewport = "true" on your scroll view

Comment: I want it to not fill the viewport, I want it to take up as little space as possible to fit its contents. Still, I've tried setting fillViewport to true and false and it made no difference.